# Simple objective-c GET request

Tags: objective-c, http, get

Most of the information here refers to the abandoned ASIHTTPREQUEST project so forgive me for asking again.

Effectively, I need to swipe a magnetic strip and send the track 2 data to a webservice that returns "enrolled" or "notenrolled" (depending on the status of the card...)

So my data comes in simply as

```
NSData *data = [notification object];
```

And then I need to pass this to a url to the order of

http://example.com/CardSwipe.cfc?method=isenrolled&track2=data

And then just receive a response string...

I've searched a ton and there seems to be some conflicting answers as to whether this should be accomplished simply with AFNetworking, RESTkit, or with the native NSURL/NSMutableURLRequest protocols.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The options for performing HTTP requests in Objective-C can be a little intimidating. One solution that has worked well for me is to use `NSMutableURLRequest`. An example (using ARC, so YMMV) is:

```
- (NSString *) getDataFrom:(NSString *)url{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

    NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

    if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
        NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %i", url, [responseCode statusCode]);
        return nil;
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
}
```

**Update:**

Your question's title, and tagging say POST, but your example URL would indicate a GET request. In the case of a GET request, the above example is sufficient. For a POST, you'd change it up as follows:

```
- (NSString *) getDataFrom:(NSString *)url withBody:(NSData *)body{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    /* the same as above from here out */ 
}
```

Comment: OK cool thanks for the quick response. I'm a bit confused as to how exactly this passing any data? Looks like a function to simply connect to a http service?

Comment: The POST sample passes data via the line `[request setHTTPBody:body]` and arrives in the HTTP body. The GET example would pass data on the URL, so you'd have to format your URL ahead of time... perhaps using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com?param1=%@&param2=%@", param1, param2]`.

Comment: So this is returning "<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>Enrolled</string></data></wddxPacket>" to the NSLOG which is the same as the page source. The actual page is outputting Enrolled though. I suppose it's a trivial difference in the sense that I could parse everything else, but is this code returning the page data rather than the proper output?

Comment: My suggestion is to look at a framework like CF-Networking or ASIHttpRequest (although not ARC compliant) to do this kind of work.

Comment: @JenScott, this code simply returns everything. You're question stated that you wanted a response string, and this code will literally return you everything the web server returns... I often couple this technique with `SBJson` if I'm parsing JSON, or another library as appropriate.

Comment: Gotcha --so I do need to parse the response, even though the webserver seems to already do this for the browser.

Answer (score 26):

Update for iOS 9:
So, `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest]` is deprecated starting from iOS 9. Here's how to do a GET request using `NSURLSession` starting from iOS 9

**GET Request**

```
// making a GET request to /init
NSString *targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/init", baseUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {

      NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", myString);
}] resume];
```

**POST Request**

```
// making a POST request to /init
NSString *targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/init", baseUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

//Make an NSDictionary that would be converted to an NSData object sent over as JSON with the request body
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"basic_attribution", @"scenario_type",
                     nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {

      NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", responseStr);
}] resume];
```

Comment: Just tried something very similar for the GET example  (just inserting a website that I know puts out valid data) in a new project (enabled ARC project-wide) on Xcode 11 for iOS 13; bombs with 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACC' - anyone else try this or recompile an existing project?

Answer (score 3):

**Tested 100% working**

Only for **Objective C**

```
-(void)fetchData
{

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

    // Setup the request with URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.orgorg.net/ios/getStory.php?"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Convert POST string parameters to data using UTF8 Encoding
    NSString *postParams = @"";
    NSData *postData = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Convert POST string parameters to data using UTF8 Encoding
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Create dataTask
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        //JSON Parsing....
        NSString *message = results[@"Message"];
        BOOL status = results[@"Status"];
        if (status){
           // Here you go for data....

        }else{
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"App"
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; // 1
            UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                      NSLog(@"You pressed button one");
                                                                  }]; // 2


            [alert addAction:firstAction]; // 4

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }



    }];

    // Fire the request
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Just 1 method, is most simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Objective c :

```
-(void)loadData:(NSString*)url{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = (NSMutableArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loadingData:)]){
        
        [self.delegate loadingData:jsonArray];
    }
}] resume];
```

}

Swift 5.5:

```
    // MARK: - Posts
func getPosts(endPath : String, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
    let urlPath = Constants.Network.BASE_URL + endPath
    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = Constants.Network.HTTPS_METHOD
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(decodedResponse)
                }
                return
            }
        }
        print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Simply Call and get your JSON Data.**

-(void)getJSONData
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/json"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *data = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSError *erro = nil;

    if (data!=nil) {

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&erro ];

        if (json.count > 0) {

            for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){

                [arr addObject:[[[json[@"feed"][@"entry"] objectAtIndex:i]valueForKeyPath:@"im:image"] objectAtIndex:0][@"label"]];
           }

        }
    }
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        [table reloadData];
    });
}];

[data resume];
}
```