# fetch ID3 tags without downloading the whole file in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, mp3, id3

Is it possible to fetch ID3 tags (especially duration) without downloading the hole file?

I need to get the duration of mp3 files from http urls.

I'd tried to do this :

`AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSString *duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)];`

but it takes time especially when it is a big file.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

**short answer: yes** if they are ID3v2 tags

**which ID3 Tag version are you trying to read?**

**ID3v1 tags** are at the end of a file, in the last 128 bytes. With Net::HTTP it doesn't seem to be possible to seek forward towards the end of the file and read only the last N bytes. If you try that, using headers = {"Range" => "bytes=128-"} , it always seems to download the complete file. resp.body.size => file-size . But no big loss, because ID3 version 1 is pretty much outdated at this point because of it's limitations, such as fixed length format, only ASCII text, ...). iTunes uses ID3 version 2.2.0.

**ID3v2 tags** are at the beginning of a file - to support streaming - you can download the initial part of the MP3 file, which contains the ID3v2 header, via HTTP protocol >= 1.1

I answered pretty much the same question before, which was specifically for a Ruby implementation.

**Please check this Question:** 
[Read ID3 Tags of Remote MP3 File in Ruby/Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656950/read-id3-tags-of-remote-mp3-file-in-ruby-rails)

---

**Continued..**
The Ruby code in the other question I mentioned is a fully functioning example.

You can set a pre-determined size of bytes you want to fetch which is large enough that you assume it contains the complete ID3-tag, e.g. 1000 bytes

You then open an HTTP connection using your favourite HTTP library for whatever language you use, but make sure that the version of the HTTP-protocol is >= 1.1 , and you read the first 1000 Bytes using the HTTP option "Range" , which only downloads a given range of bytes from the file you are trying to access via HTTP.

The concrete implementation on iOS depends on what libraries you use.

**Here is an example in Objective-C for a GET request:** 
  [Simple objective-c GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404104/simple-objective-c-get-request)

All you need to do is to pass a Range-header to the request, which specifies the range.

See API: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Also check the example for how the Range header field needs to be formatted:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

e.g. this is the syntax for the Range header:

```
 Range: bytes=0-1000
```

You'll need to set this header via the addValue:forHTTPHeaderField instance method.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is how to download the initial part and fetch it?

Comment: I added to my answer - please check the Mac Developer Library documents for the specifics of the method calls. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html