# How can I push files to a non-jailbroken iPad/iPhone from the OSX terminal?

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

Edit: Assume the device is not jailbroken

Here's what I've done so far: 
I have looked at libimobiledevice and ifuse. From what I could tell, they were basically developed for Linux, but they are supposed to work on OSX. I was able to compile them for OSX by using Homebrew, but I have not been able to figure out how to actually use ifuse as it takes a mount path, and OSX doesn't seem to expose the device's mount path.

Has anyone actually been able to access the Documents directory on the iPad/iPhone via the OSX terminal window?  How did you do it?

Comment: If you are aiming at jailbroken devices, please consider adding the jailbreak tag.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to comment about that. I am not referring to jailbroken devices.  This is for a work device and we just need this functionality for automation.

Answer (score 3):

The mount point is the path on **your Mac** where you want to mount the app's Documents folder. For example, with [ifuse 1.1.3](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse), to mount the Documents folder of an app as a folder called `MyApp` on your desktop:

```
ifuse --documents <BundleID> ~/Desktop/MyApp
```

Make sure `~/Desktop/MyApp` exists before trying to mount the device.

Comment: Wow, I guess I never realized that because I get a Fuse4x kernel extension error whenever I try to do it.

Comment: Did you have to do anything special to fix this error? I have found only minimal information online, and it seems Fuse4X has been replaced with osxfuse.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions found via `brew info fuse4x-kext` to correctly install the kernel extension?

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as needing a simple host for an http get.  What's worked well for me is to place the file on volatile host like [FileTea](https://filetea.me), and add a text field in my app where you type the url for a get.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I might be able to integrate a http get call from the Objective C, but I would really prefer to not edit the code if possible. I found this link that may prove useful if we go down this path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404104/simple-objective-c-get-request